# How can I disable natural copy & paste in Terminal?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I am a vim user and I need to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> from time to time. Currently it pastes clipboard contents into terminal. In Luna,  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> was used for pasting. How can I change the behavior of the terminal?

I don't want to remap the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> action.

Thanks in advance,
Magnus.

Comment: This is only partially related, but maybe still worth mentioning:
SHIFT+INS does the same thing. Something that I found very useful on MS DOS, if I remember correctly...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The ability to paste clipboard contents into the terminal using the standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> shortcut is called "natural-copy-paste" and you can disable it in the dconf settings.

If you haven't already done so, install **dconf editor** using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Open **dconf editor** and navigate to **org > pantheon > terminal > settings**.
Once you're there, you can untick the option.

[image]

Now pasting into the terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> no longer works, and the former default shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) is restored.

Comment: For elementary OS 5.0 Juno the correct path is: `io.elementary.terminal.setttings`

Answer (score 8):

If you prefer to do things in the terminal, simply run:

```
gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings natural-copy-paste false
```

Before Elementary OS 5.0, it was:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings natural-copy-paste false
```

Answer (score 5):

For Elementary OS 5.x Juno, it has been set to a new location:

`gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings natural-copy-paste false`

Answer (score 2):

The 5.5.0 release of Terminal (4th Jan 2020) added the option to toggle Natural Copy/Paste in the Settings menu: https://github.com/elementary/terminal/releases/tag/5.5.0
So now you can change this via the UI.

This was also mentioned in Elementary's blog: https://blog.elementary.io/hera-updates-for-january-2020/#terminal