# Ctrl + C cant kill process in terminal

Tags: pantheon-terminal, gnome-terminal, processes

i'm sorry for my bad english, 
how to kill process in terminal on elementary OS? 
but when i use onboard keyboard, i can use this method (Ctrl + C).

FYI : my keyboard is fine (works in my windows)

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Ctrl+C should kill processes running in the foreground of the terminal where you're sending the keyboard sequence. If they don't terminate, they are not responding correctly to `SIGINT`. You can try to kill them forcibly with `SIGKILL` (`kill -9 $pid_of_process_to_terminate`) if you really have to.

Comment: see [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/how-can-i-disable-natural-copy-paste-in-terminal/2068#2068) that worked for me.

Comment: The same problem. Did you already resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

In Terminal's settings, toggle off *Natural Copy/Paste* as shown in the image below.
Now *Ctrl+C* should work as you expect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try turning off "natural copy paste" option in elementary tweaks.